# CameraX beta03 and bottom sheet scroll issue

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-camerax

I was upgrading cameraX `alpha` to `1.0.0-beta03` in my project. I am following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#0). Everything is working and I am able to take an image as expected.

But I have a bottom sheet in the camera fragment. After I have implemented the beta03, while scrolling the bottom sheet, it seems to be overlapped by some invisible view, like this:

[image]

After debugging for some time found out this is only happening when I pass `camera?.cameraInfo` to `viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider`. If I pass null, this issue is not happening. But I don't know the implications of this.

```
preview?.setSurfaceProvider(
                viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider(camera?.cameraInfo))
```

**When I pass null here, The bottom sheet completely comes up.**

This is what the documentation says:

```
/**
     * Gets the {@link Preview.SurfaceProvider} to be used with
     * {@link Preview#setSurfaceProvider(Executor, Preview.SurfaceProvider)}.
     * <p>
     * The returned {@link Preview.SurfaceProvider} will provide a preview
     * {@link android.view.Surface} to the camera that's either managed by a
     * {@link android.view.TextureView} or {@link android.view.SurfaceView}. This option is
     * determined by the {@linkplain #setPreferredImplementationMode(ImplementationMode)
     * preferred implementation mode} and the device's capabilities.
     *
     * @param cameraInfo The {@link CameraInfo} of the camera that will use the
     *                   {@link android.view.Surface} provided by the returned
     *                   {@link Preview.SurfaceProvider}.
     * @return A {@link Preview.SurfaceProvider} used to start the camera preview.
     */
```

I have added a random bottom sheet to google's sample app and pushed it [here(Github link)](https://github.com/jimmy-jose/CameraXBasicBottomSheetBug) with the bug reproduced. (Please build `Cameraxbasic` module. My branch is `Bug_repro_bottomsheet`)

Can someone please explain whats going on and how to fix this?

Note: I tried updating the z-index and elevation of the bottom sheet. and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `PreviewView.createSurfaceProvider()` states:

> The returned Preview.SurfaceProvider will provide a preview Surface to
>   the camera that's either managed by a TextureView or SurfaceView. This
>   option is determined by the preferred implementation mode and the
>   device's capabilities.

Note that whether the preview surface is managed by a `TextureView` or `SurfaceView` partially depends on the `CameraInfo` instance you pass into `PreviewView.createSurfcaeProvider()`.

- If you pass in `null`, `PreviewView` uses a `TextureView` by default.
- If you pass in a non-null `CameraInfo` instance, `PreviewView` will try to use a `SurfaceView`, but will fall back to using a `TextureView` on certain devices, e.g Legacy devices, devices running on API level 24 or lower, etc.

Going back to the issue you're seeing, it's happening when you pass in a non-null `CameraInfo` instance, it's probably because the device you tested on supports `SurfaceView` well, so `PreviewView` uses it.

When you pull up the bottom sheet, it stops where the `SurfaceView` ends. Even though the `SurfaceView` seems to occupy the entire screen, it only occupies a part of it (the rectangle from the top of the screen until the point where the bottom sheet stops), that's because the `SurfaceView` is scaled up to fill the entire screen (`PreviewView` calls the methods `SurfaceView.setScaleX()` and `PSurfaceView.setScaleY()` internally, causing the preview to stretch, but the bounds of the `SurfaceView`, aka the rectangle it occupies in the `View` hierarchy, doesn't change).

Going through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) of SurfaceView, you'll see that:

> The surface is Z ordered so that it is behind the window holding its
>   SurfaceView; the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its
>   surface to be displayed.

The `SurfaceView` isn't like your typical `View`, it's handled/rendered differently than a normal `View`, and its surface exists on a separate layer, independent of the graphics layer used to render the `View` hierarchy. So if you intend to have other `View`s scroll on top of the preview, you might need to force `PreviewView` to use a `TextureView` to manage the preview surface. You can do this by either passing `null` to `PreviewView.createSurfaceProvider()`, or call `PreviewView.setPreferredImplementationMode(ImplementationMode.PreviewView)`.

You can read more about `PreviewView` [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/display-a-camera-preview-with-previewview-86562433d86c).

Comment: Weird stuff. Thanks for explaining this to me. This seems to have fixed it. But will forcing ImplementationMode.PreviewView have some issue in legacy devices? My minsdk is 23

Comment: No, it shouldn't. So far, `TextureView`s seem to work fine on all API levels CameraX supports (from 21) and on legacy devices. `PreviewView` tries to use `SurfaceView` when it cans because it has a better performance than `TextureView`.

Answer (score 0):

For **androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha31** just set compatible `implementationMode` to `PreviewView` (before `setSurfaceProvider`) to fix this issue:

```
previewView.implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
```